# Is eating bovine gelatin a crime in Hinduism?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, food, cows

Many pharmaceutical medicine have bovine gelatin as an ingredient.

> Bovine Gelatin is a protein product produced by partial hydrolysis of
> collagen, a protein material, extracted from animal tissue such as
> skin and bone. It is made up of amino acids joined together by amide
> linkages in a long molecular chain.

Is this Dharmic??

Is taking these considered a crime??

Comment: How is bovine gelatin obtained/produced? Can you add that info in the question itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bovine Gelatin is a protein made from the chemical reaction of hydrolysis of collagen. Collagen is extracted from the skin and bone of animals (mostly cows). Therefore, it is not possible to make bovine gelatin without killing the animal first as you cannot harvest the inner of the bovine’s bones without the death of an animal first.

[Verses 5.48-5.52 of Manusmriti](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/dharma/manusmriti_1.asp) explain the reason for avoiding meat. But verse 5.27 of Manusmriti says that eating meat is okay if not eating meat may place a person’s health and life at risk. Therefore, if you can not avoid medicines containing bovine gelatin, it may be okay.